# ssis truncate table in ForEach ADO Enumerator

Tags: sql, ssis, truncate, enumerator, foreach-loop-container

I have been trying to truncate a number of tables in 1 DWH.
after setting my object parameter ,going into the loop
my sql statement is :
truncate table ?
after executing the following error :

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "truncate table ?"
> failed with the following error: "An error occurred while extracting
> the result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_I4)". Possible failure
> reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set
> correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
> correctly.

Comment: It's difficult to guess what script have you created for this purpose. ¿Why don't you share it, at least?

Comment: i will try to be more specific first  i did in sql task select name from sys.tabls i chose fullresult set and on result set i add new var in object data type, after i enter the loop and try to run truncate task on each table but the erorr that i wrote appered